# Change at runtime to a marker interface

Tags: java

Today I saw the next code:

```
public Tab addTab(Component c, String caption, Resource icon, int position) {
    Tab addedTab = super.addTab(c, i18nCaption, icon, position);
    // if is not securized
    if (!(addedTab instanceof SecurizedComponent)) {
        addedTab = SecurityWrapper.createSecurityWrapper((TabSheetTabImpl)addedTab, caption);
    }
    return addedTab;
}
```

SecurizedComponent is a marker interface

```
/**
 * 
 * This is a marker interface. All securized components will be changed at runtime to implement this interface.
 * This way, is possible to know if a component has been securized asking for component instanceof SecurizedComponent
 * 
 * Allows the framework not to securize components more than once
 * 
 */
   public interface SecurizedComponent {

   }
```

The method createSecurityWrapper do something like:

```
    Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
    enhancer.setSuperclass(wrapperClass);
    enhancer.setClassLoader(source.getClass().getClassLoader());
    enhancer.setInterfaces(new Class[]{SecurizedComponent.class});

    //more stuff...
```

I know what this code is doing, basically when a tab is added for the first time, it is changed at runtime to implement SecurizedComponent interface. 
But my question is: Is this a good practice? Is there a better way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't shock me, really. I would put the check `if (!(addedTab instanceof SecurizedComponent)) {` inside SecurityWrapper, so you won't have that check everywhere in your code, and calling SecurityWrapper with a securized object would do nothing.

Otherwise, I would use a Securizable interface with a isSecured() method, all implementations would return false until SecurityWrapper works his magic.

Of course that "Security" is only as secure as your code, since I support you could change your class to implement Securized and bypass the checks...